# FabricJS text issue in mobile

Tags: fabricjs

Has anyone encountered issues while working with text on fabric js for different devices?
I tested it on iPad and it works just fine but on other devices it's:

Android -> The keyboard stays up for a brief moment when you click on the screen and then disappears

iPhone -> When you click on the screen, everything zooms in and stays like that.

// A rectangle is drawn on mouse click so i get the coordinates on mouse click with getPointer

```
getTopLeftRectangleCoords() {
  const coords = {};
  coords.x = (this.textRectangle.x0 <= this.textRectangle.x1) ? this.textRectangle.x0
    : this.textRectangle.x1;
  coords.y = (this.textRectangle.y0 <= this.textRectangle.y1) ? this.textRectangle.y0
    : this.textRectangle.y1;
  return coords;
},

drawText() {
      const txt = 'Text here';
      const coords = this.getTopLeftRectangleCoords();
      const widthToFont = 155 / 37;
      let fontSize = this.getTextRectangleWidth() / widthToFont;
      if (fontSize < 70 / widthToFont) {
        fontSize = 70 / widthToFont;
      }
      this.fText = new fabric.IText(txt,
        { fontFamily, left: coords.x, top: coords.y, fontSize },
      );
```

Comment: Were you able to figure anything out?